# Issue with CSV as a source in datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a CSV

```
"Heading","Heading","Heading",LF
"Data1","Data2","Data3",LF
"Data4","Data5","Data6",LF
```

And for the above CSV row limiter is LF

Issue is last comma. When I try to preview data after setting first column as heading and skip rows as 0 in source of copy activity in data factory, it throws error stating last column is null.

If I remove last comma.ie

```
"Heading","Heading","Heading"LF
"Data1","Data2","Data3"LF
"Data4","Data5","Data6"LF
```

It will work fine.

It's not possible to edit CSV as each CSV may contain 500k records.

How to solve this?

---

Addition details:

CSV i am uploading[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glVUg.jpg)

My azure portal setting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq6ld.jpg)

Error message on preview data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNIU3.jpg)

if i remove the first row as header i could see an empty column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOFrU.jpg)

Comment: Hi,not sure what you mean. Your row delimiter is LF? Could you please post your copy pipeline json code? Or configuration screenshot on the portal?

Comment: LF-line feed.(\n). The issue is that since the input CSV as a comma before line feed it is taking as an empty column. So if I put first row as column heading it's giving error saying column name cannot be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to set `Row delimiter` as `Line Feed(\n)`.

[image]

I tested your sample csv file and it works fine.

[image]

***output:***

[image]

---

I tried to create the same file with you and reproduce your issue.It seems the check mechanism of adf. You need to remove the first row as header selection to escape this check. If you do not want to do that, you have to preprocess your CSV files.

I suggest you below two workarounds.

1.Use Azure Function Http Trigger. You could pass the CSV file name as parameter into Azure Function.Then use Azure Blob Storage SDK to process your csv file to cut the last comma.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook

2.Use Azure Stream Analytics. You could configure your blob storage as input and create another container as output. Then use SQL query to process your CSV data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-quick-create-portal

Comment: for me i am getting an error "Empty or Null string found in Column Name 4. Please make sure column name not null and try again.. Activity ID:e05af597-836b-4c68-8f74-61cc3b3d08d9" with same csv.

Comment: @boss Any differences between us? Could you please post your same configuration screenshot with me? And your sample csv file screenshot?

Comment: I added my images as a new answer as I am not able to edit my questions.

Comment: @boss Please see update answer,you could adopt two workarounds.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try

Comment: @boss Hi,any progress? If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I go for first option. I remove first row as header. Then manually map the source and destination. Thanks a lot for ur help